# How do I fix "Error 1001. Absolute path information is required."?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to install an Excel plugin for a customer and get the error

"Error 1001. Absolute path information is required"

The plugin installs fine on my own computer, but I suspect that the customer system admin might have some setting preventing a correct installation - even though they wont admit it or know it!

I suspect that it is some kind of regedit protection- can anyone confirm or deconfirm this?

The installation is on Windows 10.

P.S. I have filed a bug-report with the vendor, but it might take a while for a reply - and it works fine on my computer.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No, unfortunately the vendor pulled a "version not supported" excuse. It seemed like a wrong/bad mix of Windows 10 Pro and Office 365. but not, never solved it, sorry.